# Scons: I fail to add qt4 tool

Tags: qt, qt4, scons

I followed the following guide to the letter:

http://www.scons.org/wiki/ToolsIndex

I tried checking out lp:scons-qt4 in:

1. Directory with a project
2. ~/.scons/site_scons/site_tools
3. ~/.scons diretory

But a simple SConstruct file with a line:

```
env = Environment (tools = ['default', 'qt4'])
```

Still produces an error message:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
EnvironmentError: No tool named 'qt4': not a Zip file:
  File "/home/septi/Документы/ScanModule/SConstruct", line 3:
    env = Environment (tools = ['default', 'qt4'])
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Environment.py", line 991:
    apply_tools(self, tools, toolpath)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Environment.py", line 105:
    env.Tool(tool)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Environment.py", line 1691:
    tool = SCons.Tool.Tool(tool, toolpath, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Tool/__init__.py", line 94:
    module = self._tool_module()
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Tool/__init__.py", line 154:
    raise SCons.Errors.EnvironmentError(m)
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Maybe it's not supported in my version or something? I'm totally puzzled and don't know where to start.

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10, scons version is 2.0.0.final.0.r5023.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a tool to the .scons directory in your home was only a recent addition - you need to be using SCons 2.1 or later.

If you want to use the qt4 tool within a project, then you have to add it to `<project>/site_scons/site_tools/`. As you use the tool as "qt4", then the sub-directory must be called "qt4" within the site_tools directory. It can't be called "scons-qt4" or anything else, which may depend on the options you pass to bzr when you check out the project from launchpad.